# access ActionView helpers from inside the Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeview

I have a simple template system which calls a `show_me` method defined inside different classes of my model (kinda Widgets) when rendering a template. These widgets originally returned the html as a string. So in my erb I have somethink like this.

```
<% @template.widgets.each do |widget| %>
   <%= widget.show_me %>    
<% end %>
```

As the views of the widgets became more complex I start using partials to render them, calling the `ActionView::Base` render method from inside my widgets (please don't throw up yet :)

```
def show_me
      # ... specific calculations and other magic.
    ActionView::Base.new(MyApp::Application.config.view_path).render(:partial => "widgets/weather_widget", :locals => {:data => data, :settings => settings})  
end
```

So, this works like a charm (really...) but when I want to use helpers inside the widget specific partial (eg. `widgets/_weater_widget.html.erb`) they don't work. for example. `javascript_tag` raises

```
can't convert nil into String
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:790:in `join'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:790:in `rails_asset_id'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:813:in `rewrite_asset_path'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:742:in `compute_public_path'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:256:in `javascript_path'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:822:in `javascript_src_tag'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:362:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:362:in `collect'
actionpack (3.0.0) lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:362:in `javascript_include_tag'
```

I think I'm missing something when I create the ActionView::Base.

Any thoughts how to solve this? Also any suggestion on the overall design is welcome too :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please for the love of all things MVC don't render view code from a model. :( There is always a better way to do it.

Example:

## Model

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name
    "weather_widget"
  end

  def settings
    ## something here
  end

  def data
    ## calculations here
  end
end
```

## Helper

```
module WidgetHelper

  def render_widget(widget)
    render(:partial => "widgets/_#{widget.name}", :locals => {:data => widget.data, :settings => widget.settings})
  end

end
```

## View

```
<% @template.widgets.each do |widget| %>
  <%= render_widget(widget) %>    
<% end %>
```

Obviously that may not be the exact solution for your situation, but is just a guide to show you something that can be done to keep your code clean. :)

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to get a call to a view helper to work from a model, but Rails will fight you every step of the way.  Rails doesn't want you to do things like this.

Consider introducing a *widget presenter* class.  It could live in `app/helpers,` like

```
module WidgetHelper
  class WidgetPresenter < Struct.new(:widget)
    def show_me
      render(:partial => "widgets/#{widget.class}/show", :locals => {:widget => widget })
    end
  end

  def show_widgets(template)
    @template.widgets.map do |widget|
        WidgetPresenter.new(widget).show_me
    end.join
  end
end
```

That way you can use OO techniques to share presentation logic between widget presenters, and you can keep Rails happy (and future developers) by isolating your information from it's presentation.