# Make all ActionViewer helper methods available in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using ruby on rails 3. I have a model called `Content`. Within the controller, I extract some variables and pass them to the Viewer. In the Viewer, I would like to use of my self made functions so that I don't have too much logic and code in the Viewer. I defined these functions in the `ContentsHelper` module.

My functions defined in the ContentsHelper module are making use of ActionViewer helper functions, however these are not available in the ContentsHelper module. I am getting for example `NoMethodError: undefined method content_tag' for #<Content:0x1025b9458>` error.

How is it possible to make all the ActionViewer helper functions available?

Newbie.

following suggestion of Tim:

```
module ContentsHelper
include ActionView::Helpers
  def bla
    content_tag(:h2, self.title)        
end
```

I can run the bla method as `Content.bla` in the console. This is perfect!

But when I replacec `content_tag` with `image_tag`, then I run into trouble and get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `config'
from /Users/sonat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activemodel-3.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
from /Users/sonat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
from /Users/sonat/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:44:in `send'
```

I can see that module that is responsible of the image_tag method is missing "something". I would appreciate if you guys tell me the general approach in finding what is missing and how I could solve the problem.

Comment: what are your 'self made functions' doing? It would be helpful to seeing the code that you are describing. Rails sticks close to a set of configuration patterns. I recommend sticking really close to these patterns at first because they are proven. After awhile, you can make alterations or even contribute to the pattern itself.

Comment: Looks like you might need to make sure that the :controller module-level variable is available: http://drawohara.com/post/24582894/rails-un-suckass-ing-actionview-helpers-in-the-name

Comment: That your edit is talking about running `Content.bla` in the console is concerning.  The console does not load the _view_ context, it's really only for running _model_ methods.  There's so much context missing (like the whole `request` context) that means many things (like path helpers) can't work in the console without a lot of hacking around (which makes most efforts to use the console to test non-model methods invalid).

Comment: (cc @natedavisolds) It would really help if we could see which TagHelpers methods you're trying to leverage in your helper, so that we can advise you on whether it would be better to split this out into a half-view, half-model style, or if string-generation at the model level really is a good way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do something odd like to use the helper method inside your **model** instead of inside your **view**.  Helper methods are for views, not for models.

### Added

Tim asked if I could provide some links to other resources, but really this is such basic stuff that I'm not aware of anything dealing with this.  Mostly tutorials deal with unusual things like using helpers **outside** views.

So instead, here's some code:

#### app/helpers/contents_helper.rb

```
module ContentsHelper
  def foo
    content_tag :p, "Foo"
  end
end
```

#### app/views/contents/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing Contents</h1>

<%= foo %>
```

#### The HTML output when going to /contents URL

```
<h1>Listing Contents</h1>

<p>Foo</p>
```

And that's as hard as it is.

Comment: I agree about the oddity. And I am utterly confused I think. However, I understand that helpers are for viewers. And this is also my intention. For example: I am passing `@content` variable to a viewer. `@content.body` contains a long text and for presentation purposes I would like to shorten it, conditioned on other parameters (e.g. depending on it is content). I would not like to compute all this inside the viewer, so I need a helper which makes all this computations and  outputs a html code. So consequently I need to use the ActionViewer::Helper methods inside my helper, but donnow how to?

Comment: For example say that this is my helper: `module ContentsHelper;def shorten;content_tag(somecode);end;end`. My problem is to make `content_tag` available here...

Comment: @NoNameNo: Here's kinda what he means, by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127539/access-actionview-helpers-from-inside-the-model

Comment: See, @NoNameNo, your error message is in `Content` - which is the model class.  If you were using the view helpers in the view then the error would be in something like `#<#Class...`  So, it's clear from your error, that you're trying to use the view helper in the model.  Adding the `include` that Tim recommends is a hack, but doesn't solve the real problem which is that you're misusing view helpers.

Comment: ...also, just to clarify - you don't need to do anything magical to use ActionView methods in a helper **as long as** you're using the helper in the _view_ (ie. in your .erb or .haml file) and not in your _model_.  All the ActionView methods are available.

Answer (score 2):

content_tag:

Does this work?

```
module ContentsHelper
 include ActionView::Helpers
end
```

---

image_tag:

Looks like you'll have to make your models know where the images are located by implementing a `#path_to_image(image)` method.

I've set up a Gist for us to mock out the features you need here:

https://gist.github.com/1015333

You should be able to download and run forNoNameNo.rb (which should run quietly without errors.)

That file has some examples of what's needed to make image_tag work.

---

further discussion:

Helpers are probably the weirdest part of Rails. They're declared at the controller level, but are only included at the view level, and rely on weird parts of the controller stack for their info; and yet, the info they are mainly concerned with presenting is the model info. So they're spread across all these weird concerns.

To deal with code-organizations issues arising from all of this, people have tended toward the [Presenter pattern](http://gilesbowkett.blogspot.com/2007/10/my-version-of-rails-presenters.html). (Also see [rbates' version](http://railscasts.com/episodes/101-refactoring-out-helper-object))

That said, if you'd prefer to stray off the beaten path in rails, it's normally really useful to read the source code.

If you're using textmate:

```
    mate `gem which actionpack`../action_view
```

in Terminal.app should get your there. If you're using another editor/operating system you might have to navigate to whereever `gem which actionpack` tells you to go.

Comment: Tim please see the new edit. your suggestion partially helps me.

Comment: You're making it sound far more complicated than it is.  Helpers are not weird if you use them as they're intended.  You don't need any special `include` and you certainly don't need to read any source code.  You add a method to the helper, then call that method from the view.  QED.

Comment: @Jason, could you help by providing links to presenters and view model tutorials in your answer, so @NoNameNo can see how this logic would be properly factored?

Comment: @NoNameNo please see the mentioned Gist.